# Fetch not null values first, if not found then fetch null value -Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables. `table1` has primary records. `table2` is slave table having multiple entries for `table1.id`. Some of the entries could be blank.

First if `table2.data` is set AND date is not past, then I have to get that record when I do a join of 2 tables. If there is no record with `table2.data` having not null value and date is not past, then fetch last updated record from `table2`, having `table2.data IS NULL`.

I need a single query to fetch NOT NULL or NULL record.

Table1

```
id  name   date
1   Abc    2013-12-09
2   Test   2014-12-09
3   Xyz    2012-02-10
```

Table2

```
id  user_id  data
1   1        test
2   1        NULL
3   2        NULL
4   3        blah blah.....
```

If I join 2 tables my result should be like, when I pass `user_id = 1` and comparing date as today's date

Result

```
id   user_id    data
1    1          NULL
```

If I join 2 tables my result should be like, when I pass `user_id = 2`

Result

```
id   user_id    data
1    2          NULL
```

Comment: What queries have you tried to use to get this done so far and what was your logic behind them?

Comment: Your description leaves room for interpretation. And it crumbles at `then fetch last updated record from table2`: what defines the last update in `table2`?

Answer (score 1):

This is an educated guess. Your description is too vague.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t2.user_id)
       *
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN   table2 t2 ON t2.user_id = t1.id
WHERE  t1.date > current_date
ORDER  BY t2.user_id, t2.data DESC NULLS LAST
```

Assuming:

- `table2.user_id` corresponds to `table1.id`.
- You only want rows where `table1.date` is a future date.
- `(user_id, data)` is unique in `table2`, or you need additional sort criteria.